# How can I reduce virtual memory (committed) size in my app?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, virtual-memory

My app is running .NET 4.0 and WinForm.

Mdi App and third Party controls used.

When it is running, getting grows still virtual memory (committed) size.
I could reduce and release WorkingSet size with such as lines

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(p.Handle, -1, -1);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);
```

It is working well.
Well, a couple of screens must be open for business logic, so the memory size is still growing, and finally dead the app.

But I could not reduce or release virtual memory size its growed already.

I was tried to configuration in app.config

```
<runtime>
<DisableDoubleMapping enabled="true" />
<gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

It is not working.
Any effects on it.

I was tried to view with VMMap 3.1.
Images are mostly .net ngen image.
The part of assemblies and additional references dlls are not big that much.
Of course some of dll (third pary controls for winform) about 5~6MB.

How can I reduce virtual memory(commited) size in my app?

Please let me know better way as soon as possible.
Like this

```
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(p.Handle, -1, -1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's no magic wand, you have to write smarter code.  Reducing the working set size is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what is causing your memory to grow in the first place. .NET Memory Profiler is a good tool for this, as you can take snapshots over time and compare them to one another. You'll be able to see what objects are "leaking," and it will give you the allocation & root stacks for those objects so you can fix your code to release the references.

On a side note, `DisableDoubleMapping` in your `app.config` file is useless in .NET 4. It was added as a workaround for a bug in the .NET Framework 3.5 that caused assemblies to be loaded twice into memory. You can read more about it in [Microsoft's hotfix page for KB981266 (archived version)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111109171703/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981266/en-us).